# CGI not working with httpd server on busybox 1.15.0 on ltib linux 2.6.34 (404 page not found)

Tags: linux, cgi, http-status-code-404, apache, busybox

I have some industrial ARM linux board with 2.6.34 Linux on it with Busybox v1.15.0.

The **https.conf** is located in ***/etc/*** and contains:

```
H:/root/www
```

In the **www** directory I also have **cgi-bin** folder with ***chmod 777*** and in that folder a file called **testcgi**.

Now I start the server with ***httpd -v*** on the target. I can access the index.html by typing the IP of the target from my host. But If I want to execute my cgi script by calling `IP-of-the-target/cgi-bin/cgitest` in the browser I get "404 page not found".

I also tried to put some directives in my **https.conf** like `A:*` or `/root/www/cgi-bin:foo:bar` but then if I try to run the server in the console I get:

```
): No such file or directory
```

So I am completely stuck here, need you help please.

Oh and I checked some articles about httpd like:
http://wiki.chumby.com/index.php/Using_the_busybox_HTTP_server

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/http.httpd

and they don't tell anything about turning the CGI on, imlplying the CGI should work on httpd by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It turned out to be a permission issue.  I was starting httpd with '/etc/init.d/httpd start' but the script was using the -u switch to set the user to httpd.  I removed '-u httpd' from the init.d script, ran /etc/init.d/restart, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You just have a wrong file name: you called it `testcgi` but calling `cgitest`.
I'll recommended to rename it to `test.cgi` or even `test.sh`. If the cgi script is main e.g. like `index.php` then you can call it `index.cgi` and the you can just specify a directory without the `/cgi-bin/index.cgi`.

You can start the bb httpd in non-daemon mode with logging and you'll see errors:

```
busybox httpd -f -vv -p 8080
```

Here the `-vv` is a verbose mode and `-f` means "Don't daemonize" in keep in foreground.

Also please note the permission to a folder may be not ehough and you may need to specify a permission for the specific script

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
I found that my device didn't have bash installed, but my script began with #!/bin/bash. Changing this to #!/bin/sh solved the 404, and my script executed.